# Email powershell as table in email body

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

i am trying to get the below to send as an email. In powershell the output is fine but when i try and send it to email i get a table but not any of the info

```
Get-VM VMName, @{Name="TotalSnapshots";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_ | Measure-Object).Count}},@{Name="TimeStamp";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_ | Select-Object CreationTime).CreationTime}}
```

This is what the email sends. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

manged to work it out...Select-Object instead of format table doh!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).